# Asp.net MVC - How to edit list of properties from Model in edit view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have model called **Line**, which contains collection of **Station**:

```
public class Line
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Station> Stations { get; set; }
}
public class Station
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int lineId { get; set; }
    public virtual Line Line { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create EDIT page for **Line** model. But I want to edit also associated **Stations** here.
For now, i have something like this, but it is not working correctly:

```
@model Factory.DomainModels.Line
@for (int i=0; i<Model.Stations.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Stations.ToList()[i].id)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Stations.ToList()[i].name)
}
```

It display editors correctly with correct values, but when i hit submit button, these values are not send to my controller, so I can not edit them.

Comment: "these values are not send to my controller"...are they inside your form? Or, are they being _sent_, but just not being bound to the model? There's a difference. Use your browser's developer tools to see what actually is sent.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for comment. They are sent, but not bounded to model.

Comment: I think you need to have a "Collection" id for each station. Without this collection id, model binder won't be able to do its job: all editors will have the same id. ```@Html.Edior($"{Model.Stations[i].id}_Name", Model.Stations[i].name)```.

Answer (score 0):

As peljoe noted in the comment, it is something like this:

```
@model Factory.DomainModels.Line
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Stations.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBox("Stations[" + i + "].id", Model.Stations[i].id)
    @Html.TextBox("Stations[" + i + "].name", Model.Stations[i].name)
}
```